# React Google Analytics - Events sending but not showing up

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I'm using [react-ga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga) for Google Analytics:

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

ReactGA.initialize("UA-XXXXXXXXX-X", { debug: true });
ReactGA.pageview("/example");

ReactGA.event({
    category: "Test",
    action: "Click",
    label: "Example"
});
```

This results in the following output:

[image: Output]

Which makes me think that everything worked, but Google Analytics doesn't show the event on my dashboard. I also tried the following:

```
ReactGA.ga("send", "event", "Test", "Click", "Example");
```

Which gave the same output, but with nothing showing up on my GA dashboard. I've waited over half an hour and my GA dashboard still doesn't show the data. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Note: The `pageview` does go through and shows up on my GA dashboard just fine.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `ReactGA.pageview("/example");`

Try Using
`ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);`

I am assertive it will work.

and have look at the documentation of ReactGa

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga

Scroll Down to **ReactGA.event(args)**

There must be an issue with your args

[image]

Comment: Tried using the right path for the `pageview` but still getting the same result for events. Also I'm using all the required args for events.

Comment: Glad. It Worked. But Do look for more as GA shows real-time views too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was just impatient. It took a while but the events did eventually show up on my GA dashboard.